# WPF Grouped Datagrid rows not visible when added to Collection

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I am hoping that this is something simple and have just missed something obvious.  I am using MVVM and have a `Datagrid` which is bound to a `CollectionViewSource` this in turn is populated with an `ObservableCollection`, the `ObservableCollection` is initally unpopulated and added to by way of tick boxes on the UI

The problem I have is that when the `ObservableCollection` is added to, the Headers appear for the grouping on the `DataGrid` but the individual rows themselves don't.

Any help really appreciated,

Here is my XAML for the Datagrid

```
<DataGrid DataContext="{Binding GroupedBookings}"
          ItemsSource="{Binding SourceCollection}"
          AutoGenerateColumns="False"
          SelectionMode="Single"
          SelectionUnit="FullRow"
          CanUserSortColumns="True"
          SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedBooking}"
          CanUserAddRows="False">
  <DataGrid.GroupStyle>
    <GroupStyle>
      <GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
          <StackPanel>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=MemberCount.SupporterType}"
                        FontWeight="Bold"
                        Padding="3" />
          </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
      </GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
      <GroupStyle.ContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type GroupItem}">
          <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
              <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type GroupItem}">
                <Expander>
                  <Expander.Header>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                      <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Name}" />
                      <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=ItemCount}"
                                  Margin="8 0 4 0" />
                    </StackPanel>
                  </Expander.Header>
                </Expander>
              </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
          </Setter>
        </Style>
      </GroupStyle.ContainerStyle>
    </GroupStyle>
  </DataGrid.GroupStyle>
  <DataGrid.Columns>
    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Cost"
                        Binding="{Binding Cost}" />
    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Order No"
                        Binding="{Binding LinkedOrderID}" />
  </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

And my code for the Collections

```
_bookings = new ObservableCollection<Booking>(rep.Bookings_Get().Where(x => x.JobID == CurrentJob.JobID));
GroupedBookings = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(Bookings);
GroupedBookings.GroupDescriptions.Add(new PropertyGroupDescription("MemberCount.SupporterType"));
```

To confirm the observable collection is updating fine as is the `CollectionView` in the VM, the `ItemCount` in the header even increases in the UI I just can't seem to make the rows appear.

Thanks in advance

Edit:

I have changed my code to assign directly to `Bookings` as opposed to `_bookings` as per EthicalLogics suggestion but this hasn't helped `Bookings` is defined as below:

```
public ObservableCollection<Booking> Bookings
{
    get { return _bookings; }
    set
    {
        _bookings = value;
        OnPropertyChanged("Bookings");
    }

}
```

Here is `GroupedBookings`

```
public ICollectionView GroupedBookings
{
    get { return _groupedBookings; }
    set
    {
        _groupedBookings = value;
        OnPropertyChanged("GroupedBookings");
    }
}
```

Comment: can you please show where you defined _bookings , because it seems like a field not property from c# Codeing conventions

Comment: private ObservableCollection<Booking> _bookings; this is defined in my VM.  Thanks

Comment: I have ruled out it being an issue with the itemsource, if I comment out the Groupstyle xaml it updates correctly so can only assume there is a problem with my xaml in the group style...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I added the following to my XAML, turns out I had missed something small however having looked at multiple examples of using a CollectionViewSource and grouping in a data grid I only found the microsoft one to contain this as part of the GroupStyle

```
<Expander.Content>
    <ItemsPresenter />
</Expander.Content>
```

Hope this helps anyone that has a similar issue

Answer (score 0):

```
public ObservableCollection<Booking> _bookings{get;set;}
```

Binding Source must be a property not field. Because binding system uses reflection and it looks only for properties not fields.I hope this will help.

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't help, _bookings is assigned to but is returned as part of the get for Bookings and is what is used in my CollectionViewSource.  I have defined properties for all my bound elements. Thanks again, Chris

Comment: then Assign the Values to Bookings not to _bookings, because when you assign values to _bookings then it will not be notified on UI. but if you will assign it to Bookings it will be notified.

Comment: Thanks again for helping me with this, I have just given that a go and it has made no differece, for your information I have edited my question to include the code for Bookings as you can see I am using firing OnPropertyChanged and before switching to a collectionviewsource it was working fine from the Bookings ObservableCollection

Comment: I have added the definitiion for GroupedBookings, thanks, Chris